# How to transfer source code from one svn server to another?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

- we have an old SVN server which has the Solutions Plus Web Site Phase 2_A1821 source code we need this source code moved to the new SVN Server? is this possible? if yes than pls tell me the steps to follow.

Regards 
Zuhaib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using svndump:

```
svnadmin dump repositorypath | gzip > backupname.svn.gz
```

That will give you a gzipped backup of your repository. You can then copy it to the new svn server and unarchive it.

You can also try hotcopy or svnsync (although that seems like overkill for your puporse). Hotcopy will preserve some control files which svndump will probably miss. It can also run while the svn server is up.

```
svnadmin hotcopy repositorypath /path/to/backup
```

You can then gzip the backup and transfer it.

Comment: @llion do I need to install some kinda tool to run above command. I am using tortoise SVN.

Answer (score 0):

If your new server runs Windows, you can use [VisualSVNServer](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) (free), which has the ability to simply import your existing repository.